# calculating the percentage for a column of values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table rendered using javascript.  I now need to calculate the percentage for each section of the table which I'm struggling with..  AAA, BBB, CCC and DDD need to represent 100% (equal to 40.99) although I'm not sure how to get the values so that it will also work for EEE, FFF, FFF, HHH and III.  The table of the structure wont change.  Any suggestions using jquery how to collect the values in the third column for each title?

The full table is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/jskvK/

```
Title 1
AAA     0%      39.00
BBB     0%     -11.01
CCC     0%       5.00
DDD     0%       8.00
Subtotal        40.99
Title 2
EEE     0%       5.00
FFF     0%       4.00
FFF     0%       6.00
HHH     0%       3.00
III     0%       2.00
Total       41.99
```

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $('.it1').each(function(){
       tot=parseFloat($('#corpbonds_total_summary').text());
       subtot=parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
       $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text((subtot/tot)*100);    
   })

$('.item').each(function(){
    tot=parseFloat($('#DepotTable_total').text());
    subtot=parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
    $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text((subtot/tot)*100);
    if($(this).hasClass('total'))
        $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text("");  

})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jskvK/11/)

Comment: its not correct check that You used the `total` for `it1` and `title2` has a `different total` so the calculation's are **not correct**.

Comment: Again you are using the same total now you `check manually`, and find a solution.

Comment: Am i missing something, or total should be 60.99?